# Is it possible to calculate how much CPU and RAM uses block of code

Tags: c++, monitoring

Is it possible to calculate how much CPU and RAM uses block of code?

For example, I have the console app and I want calculate how much CPU and RAM uses by one method in my app.

```
//many difference methods

//method for which I want to calculate how RAM and CPU resources it uses
void test1(){
    //code
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //code

    //call test1
    test1();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your wording is unclear.    Do you intend to ask how to calculate "how much CPU and RAM is used by a block of code"?

Comment: @Peter thank, but I don't understand what exactly unclear for you? Yes, I want calculate how much RAM and CPU resources used piece of code.

Comment: Calculate?  No, not in general.  What if the function loops and/or dynamically allocates memory and/or other stuff in response to external inputs?

Comment: Your use of the word "uses" is grammatically incorrect, and completely reverses the meaning of your question.  CPU (or RAM) does not use code.   Code uses CPU (or RAM).   Not the reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Linux, try [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) and it's set of tools.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio 2013 (or higher) you can use Performance and Diagnostics hub which includes CPU Usage tool. Here's  [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/02/28/new-cpu-usage-tool-in-the-performance-and-diagnostics-hub-in-visual-studio-2013/) about it.

Comment: Yes, I known, but this way is not for me, because I use other IDE(Clion). Thank.